# Input subfigure .tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfig

I'd like to input four subfigures (2 x 2) using the figure extension `.tex`. In my MWE I could not put the figures as `subfigures`. MWE:

## R Input

```
tikz('test.tex', width = 3.543312, height = 3.543312)
plot(x = runif(10), y = 2*runif(10))
dev.off()

tikz('test1.tex', width = 3.543312, height = 3.543312)
    plot(x = runif(10), y = 2*runif(10))
dev.off()

tikz('test2.tex', width = 3.543312, height = 3.543312)
    plot(x = runif(10), y = 2*runif(10))
dev.off()

tikz('test3.tex', width = 3.543312, height = 3.543312)
    plot(x = runif(10), y = 2*runif(10))
dev.off()
```

## R Output for one figure

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.10.1 on 2018-03-03 14:05:26
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (256.08,256.08);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 49.20, 61.20) rectangle (230.88,206.88);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 71.52,174.13) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 55.93,122.44) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 93.37,101.99) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (120.02,201.15) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 91.43,185.80) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (224.15,154.88) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 80.97, 66.60) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 98.43,201.48) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 95.13,138.22) circle (  2.25);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (199.15,109.17) circle (  2.25);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (256.08,256.08);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 50.02, 61.20) -- (204.08, 61.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 50.02, 61.20) -- ( 50.02, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 88.54, 61.20) -- ( 88.54, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (127.05, 61.20) -- (127.05, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (165.57, 61.20) -- (165.57, 55.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (204.08, 61.20) -- (204.08, 55.20);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 50.02, 39.60) {0.0};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 88.54, 39.60) {0.2};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (127.05, 39.60) {0.4};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (165.57, 39.60) {0.6};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (204.08, 39.60) {0.8};

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 65.61) -- ( 49.20,205.47);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 65.61) -- ( 43.20, 65.61);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,100.58) -- ( 43.20,100.58);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,135.54) -- ( 43.20,135.54);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,170.50) -- ( 43.20,170.50);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,205.47) -- ( 43.20,205.47);

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80, 65.61) {0.0};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,100.58) {0.5};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,135.54) {1.0};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,170.50) {1.5};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 34.80,205.47) {2.0};

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 61.20) --
    (230.88, 61.20) --
    (230.88,206.88) --
    ( 49.20,206.88) --
    ( 49.20, 61.20);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (256.08,256.08);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (140.04, 15.60) {runif(10)};

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 10.80,134.04) {2 * runif(10)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## In Latex

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\onecolumn
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-35pt} 
    \caption{Testando Figuras}
    \input{test.tex}
    \input{test1.tex}
    %
    \input{test2.tex}
    \input{test3.tex}
\end{figure}

\twocolumn
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: When you say that you 'could not', why not? What happens? Probably you need to put them into boxes or minipages. If you want them to be sub-figures, you should use the facilities provided by `subfig` or, preferably, by `subcaption`. Your current code does not appear to attempt to typeset them as sub-figures at all, so it isn't altogether clear what you're doing.

Comment: It will be easier for people to reproduce if you supply the content of the `.tex` files you want to use, rather than the R code you use to produce them.

Comment: I put the `R` output, the archives `test1.tex`, `test2.tex` and `test3.tex` can be copy of `test.tex`.

Comment: Thanks. Equivalently, we can just use the same `.tex` file four times .... ;).

Comment: In what sense doesn't it work for you? I get all four plots in a figure. Of course, my plots are identical as I just fed the file in 4 times, but they are arranged 2x2.

Comment: I'd like plot the graphic arrange 2x2 with little space between one line and another and subcaption for each figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your question is not clear ... i guess similarly as [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) that each image should be inserted in `subfloat` environment
- change from two columns to  one column before image and back after image cause that image is on separate page. however i would rather that figure float in text. therefore i would use `figure*` environment. that it can appear on the same page, where is inserted (if there is enough space for image) i would load also `stfloats` package in document preamble
- off topic, but can be important: code for your image is very unnecessary complicated. use of `pgfplots` package can very simplify its code. for example:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=250,
    ymin=0, ymax=250,
    xlabel={runif(10)},
    ylabel={2*runif(10)},
    xticklabels={,0,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8,1},
    yticklabels={,0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5}
            ]
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] coordinates {
    ( 71.52,174.13) (55.93,122.44)  (93.37,101.99)  (120.02,201.15) ( 91.43,185.80)
    (224.15,154.88) (80.97, 66.60)  (98.43,201.48)  ( 95.13,138.22) (199.15,109.17)
                                            };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

(even simpler can become, if you convert marks coordinates to cm)

with use of `stfloats` package and `figure*` environment you can obtain:

[image]

complete mwe:

```
\documentclass[journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz, which load graphicx, which loads graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15,
             height=0.8\columnwidth,
             width=\columnwidth
             }
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens,caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}% should be loaded last

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[b]
    \caption{Testando Figuras}
    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{job11}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{job11}}

    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{job11}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{job11}}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: sub-figures]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx, which loads graphics
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens,caption=false]{subfig}% p. 47 of subfig manual re. IEEEtran class usage
\usepackage{hyperref}% should be loaded last

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\onecolumn
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-35pt} 
    \caption{Testando Figuras}
    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{\jobname-1}}
    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{\jobname-1}}

    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{\jobname-1}}
    \subfloat[sub-caption]{%
      \input{\jobname-1}}
\end{figure}

\twocolumn
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```